# Command to switch on/off sharing Ubuntu desktop

Tags: command-line, sharing, gsettings

I'm looking for the command for switch on or off sharing from Ubuntu settings, to be able to share image, audio, or complete remote desktop control.

In Ubuntu bionic, for example, default desktop, up right corner icon, Ubuntu settings, sharing.
There is a switch to activate deactivate sharing.

I would need to know the command to manipulate that switch.

I've been researching for "gsettings", that have a long set of options, but unable to find the command to switch that button.

Answer (score 0):

I found this : https://serverok.in/enable-remote-desktop-in-ubuntu-from-the-command-line

This works for me:

```
export DISPLAY=0.0
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino view-only false
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not so easy on the new Ubuntu releases :(

To enable desktop sharing, you have to:

1. Install `vino` package. The entry for `Desktop sharing` should appear somewhere in your applications menu.
2. You have to set some configuration parameters for vino-server, but probably the only way to do it is via `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` (the GUI to set these parameters has been removed long ago). In dconf-editor, go to `/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access` and set your parameters.
   For example, if you want to authenticate with a password, you should:
   a) set `authentication-methods` to `['vnc']`
   b) set `prompt-enabled` to `false`
   c) set `require-encryption` to `false`
   d) set `vnc-password` to base64 encoded value of the password you want to use to connect
3. Start vino-server by clicking the desktop sharing entry from the menu.

On the other system, use any VNC client (eg. Remmina, which is installed by default) to connect.

Comment: Hi raj, thanks for your answer. The machine im trying to connect is in other country, where i should install it graphical interface, but since I can't be there, nevermind I installed gdm3 or xfce4... No way to switch on sharing not being physically there. Didn't know commands were removed. It appears is just kind of to know right command, but after reading you, it's clear is not so easy... Thanks anyway

Comment: Respect to use vnc, remnina.... Vinagre.. I tried, but I was unable to get remote desktop working on Ubuntu... I did it with centOs, but was impossible for me to succeed with Ubuntu

Comment: I think it shall be possible both to install ```vino``` (using ```apt-get```) and to set parameters (using ```gsettings```) from command line. However, the problem is someone needs to login to the GUI and actually start ```vino-server``` after you configure it. You can't share the desktop if there is no desktop to share...